# How can i fold a table in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to fold a table in markdown, like:

> - this is a fold, after clicking it, it should show the table below

i only can find method based on html. like:

```
<details>
<summary>CLICK ME</summary>
table content
</details>
```

but when i input markdown table content, like this:

```
|    | UK0   | UK1   | 股票代码   | 股票简称   | 配售代码   | 配售名称   | 配售比例   | 配股价   | 配股前总股本   | 配股数   | 配股后总股本   | 股权登记日   | 缴款起始日期   | 缴款截止日期   | 上市日   | UK2    | UK3     | UK4     | UK5    | UK6    | UK7     | UK8     |
|---:|:------|:------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------|:-----------|:---------|:---------------|:---------|:---------------|:-------------|:---------------|:---------------|:---------|:-------|:--------|:--------|:-------|:-------|:--------|:--------|
|  0 | int64 | int64 | int64      | object     | float64    | object     | float64    | float64  | float64        | float64  | float64        | object       | object         | object         | object   | object | float64 | float64 | object | object | float64 | float64 |
```

it wont show the well-displayed table

how can i fold a table in markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Markdown parsers support the same syntax. The example you listed looks like the one supported on GitHub. You can try their online Markdown editor [here](https://markdown-editor.github.io/).

They advise that you add an empty line after the `<summary>` line, and also after the ending tag `</details>`. I tested with your table (and newlines) and it works there:

```
# A collapsible section with markdown
<details>
    <summary>Click to expand!</summary>
    
    |    | UK0   |
    |---:|:------|
    |  0 | int64 |
</details>
```

I've shortened your table here for the sake of brevity, but I actually used the whole in their editor.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown has different flavors. I think you're talking about the one used by Discourse or GitHub, right? Unfortunately, it is what it is, but this won't work everywhere. Take a look at the syntax below for Discourse:

```
[details="Summary"]
This text will be hidden
[/details]
```

Take a look at the supported markdown [here](https://meta.discourse.org/t/post-format-reference-documentation/19197/2)

And I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't render properly in Stack Overflow, or Reddit.

What you've used (the "+" symbol) is seen as an equivalent to the "*" symbol for creating list (at least, for this platform).

Microsoft has their own markdown format, vastly different from the one I was talking about - [click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/contribute/markdown-reference)